# EF Core 2 Fluent API OnDelete /w Cascade

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, cascade, ef-fluent-api

I feel stupid for asking; but there are no docs on what exactly `OnDelete()` targets.. (ex: principle or dependent)

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tournament>(b =>
        {
               .WithOne(e => e.Tournament);
                b.HasMany(c => c.TournamentContestants)
               .WithOne(e => e.Tournament);
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ScoreTarget>()
           .HasMany(c => c.ScoreAllocations)
           .WithOne(e => e.ScoreTarget)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TournamentContestant>()
           .HasMany(c => c.ScoreAllocations)
           .WithOne(e => e.TournamentContestant)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tournament>()
           .HasMany(c => c.ScoreAllocations)
           .WithOne(e => e.Tournament)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

1. Expecting above to delete `ScoreAllocation` when deleting `ScoreTarget`, `T..Contestant` or `Tournament` (but i'm not able to test because of **Err**)
2. Can someone please explain which table the onDelete function is targeting?
3. Also, must I configure this the other way as well if only 1 way should be cascading?

**Err**: *The association between entity types 'Tournament' and 'TournamentContestant' has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, then set up the relationship to use cascade deletes.*

Comment: You don't have any Delete behavior between Tournement and TournamentContestant entities. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ilkerkaran But the default is Restrict, as it should be for Tournament..TournamentContestants. Because I don't want to allow deletion of Trounament to be possible if Contestants are associated.

Comment: `OnDelete` controls what happens with dependents when you delete the principal.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok so all my code above is backwards, right?

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle Your code looks fine for the 3 relationships mentioned in (1). The error indicates that you are trying to delete `Tournament` having dependent `TournamentContestant`s.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok looks like you were right, i guess i have more studying to do in regards to fluent api -> The answer was to ensure that the MOST parent Entity in this case Tournament had all 3 child entities set to cascade delete, even though the allocation isn't part of any of those relations (allocation is the grandchild of 2 of the children) in order for it to delete properly. if i kept the child entities with the cascade as well it ran into cyclic errors.

Comment: @IvanStoev Also, i'm betting this had to be done as i'm attaching the grandchild to parent, for easy lookup. In other words it may have worked above if i didn't have this parent.grandchild relation. (but thats theory for now) thanks again - happy to accept an answer if you want to create one.